# phonegap android tap event on ajax element using jquery

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, tap

Trying to put a tap on a element after ajax is called using jquery and jquery.tap.min.js. A function is called on a button click.

```
 function onDeviceReady() {

            function onSuccessGeo(position) {
                var datastr = "data1=XXXXX&data2=XXXX";

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: datastr,
                    url: 'http://somesite.com/sample.php',
                    success: function(html)
                    {           
                        //THESE ARE ELEMENTS CALLED IN AJAX         
                        $("#frames-inner").html(html);
                        $('.frame-container').attr("style","width: 50%;float:left;");
                        $('.frame-container2').attr("style","width: 50%;float:left;");
                        $('.frame-choice').attr("style","width: 100%;");


                            //THIS IS THE CODE TO PUT TAP LISTENER
                            $(".frame-sample").tap(function() {
                                frame_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                                frameURL = $(this).children('.frame-choice-image').attr('src');
                                capturePhoto();                 
                            });

                    }
                });     
            }
}
```

There seems to be no problem on the first load and everything works fine. But when the ajax is called again an error occurs.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tap' at file:///android_asset/www/main.html:224
```

Not sure what went wrong, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is .frame-sample on an element that is loaded from the Ajax call?

Comment: yes .frame-sample is a element that is loaded when ajax is called. All the elements inside success of ajax call are part of the ajax site that is called